# Indirect access to a static member inspection

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, intellij-14

*Eclipse* has had an "[Indirect access to static member](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcompiler%2Fref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm)" inspection available for ages:

[image]

Effectively, the following code will produce a warning when compiled with *ecj*:

```
class A {
    static void doSmth() {}
}

class B extends A {}

class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        B.doSmth();
    }
}
```

How can I enable the same inspection for *IDEA*? There're dozens of options, but it seems this particular one is merely not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to the **Intellij Preference**
2. Select **Inspections**
3. Select **Static method referenced via subclass**